# Calculation of approval rates

Tags: percentages

Total requests=100
Requests Approved=25
Requests Pending=65
Requests Rejected=5

So how to calculate the percentage of approval?? Can someone help please..

Comment: Do you know what the percentage of approval means?

Comment: ya like how much percentage of requests has been approved..

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this just the percentage of requests approved out of the total number of requests:

$$\frac{25}{100} = 0.25 = 25\text{%} $$

Comment: Yes that is correct, which is why I was wondering if the original poster knew what the percentage of approval means...

Comment: @fixedp, yes OP doesn't seem to know.

Comment: what if the total requests is 342, total approved is 22, total rejected is 20 and pending is 300..

Comment: All you need is the total number of approved and the total requests. So it would be $\large \frac{22}{342} = 6.43\text{%}$

Comment: ok. thanks alot...i got confused a bit with a simple math..

Comment: @rahul please check so other users know you have found an answer

Comment: 22/342 * 100= answer

Comment: @rahul yes you are correct. I meant to checkmark my answer above sorry if it wasn't clear